# Unable to connect to my local Oracle database through Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Unable to connect to my local Oracle 21c database using Oracle SQL Developer. Until now everything was fine. I set up tnsnames.ora as suggested:

my_test_database =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
)
)

I also could connect to my database using sqlplus \ as sysdba command. But every attempt to connect to my database (SYS user) through SQL Developer Error appears 12514 TNS: listener does not currently know of service. I am very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: what does tnsping show?  Also run lsnrctl with "status" command and see what it shows.

Comment: Your SQL\*Plus connection is bequeath (to CDB not PDB), and is not using TNS or `tnsnames.ora`. Are you using a TNS connection in SQL Developer, or a basic one where you supply the details in the connection configuration; if the latter do they match what you showed for the TNS entry, and does that service name match your actual PDB service name? `lsnrctl status` or `lsnrctl services` should provide useful information.

Comment: @Alex Poole, lsrctl status shows (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-U0RP4Q0)(PORT=1521))); lsnrctl services shows the same. I am using Basic connection where I am using such parameters: Hostname: DESKTOP-U0RP4Q0; Service Name: ORCL; PORT=1521

Comment: If `snrtctl services` doesn't show the specific service, the database is not registering to that listener. It may be a configuration problem (at instance level). When you connect locally with `/ as sysdba` you don't go through the listener. Are you sure the database is up and running without problems?

Comment: Do those commands also say "The listener supports no services", or do they show one or more services? The CDB at least seems to be up as you can connect through SQL\*Plus; when you're connected, what does `show parameters local_listener` show? One possibility is that your IP address is set via DHCP and has changed, and that parameter is using the old one, not the host name - meaning it can't register with the listener. But that's just a guess really.

Comment: @Alex Poole, local_listener                       string      LISTENER_ORCL

Comment: @DiegoFerruchelli, it shows:
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-U0RP4Q0)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully

Comment: If I understand it right, you're trying to connect to service "ORCL" (that's a default name, by the way) and the listener is accepting connections for service "CLRExtProc" (which is an agent for special purposes, and not a real database). If your connection string is ok, it's a problem between the DB (actually, the instance) and the listener. Can you reboot the instance?

Comment: @KirillDegtyarev - and how is that defined in your `tnsnames.ora`? Please add your tnsnames.ora, listener.ora and the output of the commands you're running as formatted test in the question, not as comments (or images). It still sounds like you have a hostname or IP address mismatch somewhere.

Comment: @KirillDegtyarev In SQL*Plus, what does `show pdbs` list? If you have a PDB with name ORCLPDB it will register with a service called the same + the value of parameter db_domain. If this is a default setup I guess you may have a PDB called ORCLPDB1.